# Join of recursively enumerable set and its complement

Tags: computability, undecidability

The union of a recursively enumerable set and its complement is $\Sigma^*$, which is definitely recursively enumerable. What if instead we consider the following operation, on an RE set $S$?
$$
\{ \# w : w \in S \} \cup \{ \\\$ w : w \in \overline{S} \}
$$
Is the result recursively enumerable?

Comment: The question in the body doesn't really match the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation you described in actually the join operator in the semilattice of [Turing degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree), defined as $A\sqcup B=\{0x | x\in A\}\cup \{1x | x\in B\}$. It is not hard to show that $A,B\le_T A\sqcup B$, thus if $A\in RE\setminus R$ then $\overline{A}\notin RE$ and thus $A\sqcup\overline{A}\notin RE$.